# Cannot ping B from A until B pings A

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, arp

I have a server cluster all connected on a local network(all physical machines, not virtual).  When trying to ping from Server A to B, I get a `Desitination Host Unreachable`.  I can ping from B to A no problem, which then allows me to ping from A to B for a short while. Because of this behavior I believe I have an ARP issue, although I do not know how to fix it.  When running `arp -a` I get the following result `? (10.0.0.105) at <incomplete> on eth1`, which is the IP I am trying to ping.  Not sure if it will help at all but here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` files for the both machines(I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server).

```
Server A
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0

Server B
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.105
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Every other server(I have 7 in this network) can be pinged / can ping any other server.  It is just a problem between these two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit

```
Server A
iptables --list 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Server B
iptables --list

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: How is your iptables configured on both?

Comment: Updated with iptables for both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does sound like a arp problem, if its long spanned vlan over a vpn or similar, you may need to add static arp entries, with an ether address of the local switch.

```
arp -s <destination address> <mac address> -i <interface to go out via>
```

And if thats the fix, you will have to add this to command to start up scripts.

Comment: Is ether the mac address or ethernet port? And which machine do I add this too? Server A(10.0.0.102), or Server B(10.0.0.105)? I would've thought I would have to do `arp -s <ether> 10.0.0.105` from on the 10.0.0.102 since I cannot ping from that machine.

Comment: Add it to the server that cant ping, ether address is the mac address. If these two servers are on the same local broadcast lan, then this isnt the solution, could you descript your network?

Comment: This worked, the command I used was `arp -s <Dest IP> <MAC address> -i eth1` for any future people that have this problem.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Ah sorry, my solution was for solaris, ill add the -i to answer for ubuntu

Comment: Oh and I am not 100% sure how the servers are hooked up, I dedicated boxes at a data center.

Comment: you might want to raise a support call with your kind network people, you shouldnt have to add this, the switches might prefer to do the arp proxying, but tell them what you did to fix it and theyll understand what to do.

Comment: Will do, just wanted a quick fix and to make sure it wasn't something on my end.  Thank you again.