# S2S VPN - cannot ping B from A until A pings B

Tags: networking, vpn, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan, arp

I'm working on site-to-site VPN between 2 networks within private cloud. On both ends I installed Strongswan and established VPN connection.

The problem is that I'm not able to ping from A (10.0.1.0/24) to B (172.30.0.0/16). And what is weird, when I perform ping from B to A, it is fixing traffic from A to B, but only for some time, but I'm not certain what exactly is causing that issue, probably not rekeying.

A's (65.21.51.x and 10.0.1.x) VPN gateway /etc/ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
conn A-to-B
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=65.21.51.x
    leftid=65.21.51.x
    leftsubnet=10.0.1.0/24
    right=195.201.46.x
    rightid=195.201.46.x
    rightsubnet=172.30.0.0/16
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart
```

B's (195.201.46.x and 172.30.0.x) /etc/ipsec.conf

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
conn B-to-A
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=195.201.46.x
    leftid=195.201.46.x
    leftsubnet=172.30.0.0/16
    right=65.21.51.x
    rightid=65.21.51.x
    rightsubnet=10.0.1.0/24
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart
```

ipsec statusall on A (problematic one) after restarting tunnel:

```
Listening IP addresses:
  65.21.51.x
  10.0.1.x
Connections:
A-to-B:   child:  10.0.1.0/24 === 172.30.0.0/16 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
A-to-B[2]: ESTABLISHED 2 minutes ago, 65.21.51.x[65.21.51.x]...195.201.46.x[195.201.46.x]
A-to-B[2]: IKEv2 SPIs: 9eafc9ec4ffa378f_i 72859622332da6cb_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 13 minutes
A-to-B[2]: IKE proposal: 3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
A-to-B{5}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c2b406e2_i c801b7d3_o
A-to-B{5}:  3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying disabled
A-to-B{5}:   10.0.1.0/24 === 172.30.0.0/16
```

And after it failed:

```
Listening IP addresses:
  65.21.51.x
  10.0.1.14
Connections:
A-to-B:  65.21.51.x...195.201.46.x  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
A-to-B:   local:  [65.21.51.x] uses pre-shared key authentication
A-to-B:   remote: [195.201.46.x] uses pre-shared key authentication
A-to-B:   child:  10.0.1.0/24 === 172.30.0.0/16 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
```

A's ip route:

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 65.21.51.x metric 100 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10 proto dhcp src 10.0.1.x metric 100 
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.1.x metric 100 
172.30.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10 proto static metric 100 onlink
```

A's iptables-save output:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jan  3 11:19:49 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [134136:140300437]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [93293:11784956]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan  3 11:19:49 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jan  3 11:19:49 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [668:57544]
:INPUT ACCEPT [135:20236]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [753:60165]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [226:25545]
-A POSTROUTING -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.0.0/16 -o ens10 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.0.0/16 -o ens10 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan  3 11:19:49 202
```

Few lines of logs from /var/log/syslog from A server:

```
Jan  3 11:00:07 A charon: 10[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
Jan  3 11:00:07 A charon: 10[IKE] CHILD_SA dyvenia-infra-dev_dyvenia-faam-prod{5} established with SPIs c2b406e2_i c801b7d3_o and TS 10.0.1.0/24 === 172.30.0.0/16
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[KNL] creating delete job for CHILD_SA ESP/0xc2b406e2/65.21.51.x
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[IKE] closing expired CHILD_SA dyvenia-infra-dev_dyvenia-faam-prod{5} with SPIs c2b406e2_i c801b7d3_o and TS 10.0.1.0/24 === 172.30.0.0/16
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c2b406e2
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[IKE] scheduling CHILD_SA recreate after hard expire
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 8 [ D ]
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 65.21.51.x[4500] to 195.201.46.x[4500] (68 bytes)
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 12[KNL] creating delete job for CHILD_SA ESP/0xc801b7d3/195.201.46.x
Jan  3 11:00:43 A charon: 01[NET] received packet: from 195.201.46.x[4500] to 65.21.51.x[4500] (68 bytes)
```

I don't know what else might be interesting, please let me know what I can send to help with fixing that.

What is also important is that it was working like a charm earlier. I needed to reinstall B VM and after that, it stopped working.

I also tried to play with arp, but it doesn't seem to change anything so maybe it's not a case like this one: [Cannot ping B from A until B pings A](https://serverfault.com/questions/521928/cannot-ping-b-from-a-until-b-pings-a)

In addition I created new VM that could replace A, and I have the same problem. And I also created new VM similar to B, and connecting A' with B', the problem is the same. So it might be something I set incorrectly that is causing the issue, but it's hard to say what exactly it is.

EDIT I also did some test during the night and it seems that I found workaround that might help with finding solution. I executed `nohup ping 10.0.1.x &` so basically from B to A network, and everything is working with that. So the problem is that tunnel is being removed when there is no traffic and new one is not established.

Comment: please add to the question, which subnet is used where as it does makes it easier to understand

Comment: @djdomi I added info about A (10.0.1.0/24) and B (172.30.0.0/16) and their public gateway IPs (65.21.51.x and 195.201.46.x). Is it easier to understand now or should I add more context?

Comment: just as verification, a private cloud, in your meaning, is that for your private purposes only?

Comment: It was simplification, it’s public cloud but small one, hetzner, so they don’t have too much options to configure. Only firewall and routing, both seems like created correctly, ICMP is open for everyone on firewall and ports 500/4500 are open on tcp and udp. Routing is added, but the problem is already on gateway server so from my perspective it’s not related